# Room's `onDelete = CASCADE` not working during a migration

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have the following tables:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "users"
)
class Users {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long? = null

    @NonNull
    var name: String? = null
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "pets",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Users::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["owner_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
class Pets {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long? = null

    @NonNull
    var name: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "owner_id")
    var ownerId: Long? = null
}
```

When I run a migration that deletes all users table rows, the pets table is not affected. The rows are not automatically deleted.

```
object Migration_1_2 : Migration(1, 2) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("""
            DELETE FROM users
        """)
    }
}
```

Even when I execute the following snippet of code before the migration it does not work.

```
database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```

What should I do to make the `onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE` work?

Comment: It seems that 'PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON' inside migrate block doesn't switch this mode on. With RoomDatabase you can set it inside onOpen callback, but it's too late, since migration block invokes before it. There is some chance to call method setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled() using callback [onConfigure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) of SQLiteOpenHelper, but I don't  know how to do that from inside RoomDatabase class

Comment: As the comment from @sergiytikhonov indicates, enabling the `foreign_keys` constraint in a migration function has no effect.  This is because migrations are executed as part of a transaction and [the pragma is a no-op inside a transaction](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#:~:text=PRAGMA%20foreign_keys%20%3D%20boolean%3B,no%20pending%20BEGIN%20or%20SAVEPOINT.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sergiytikhonov indicates in his comment, enabling the foreign_keys constraint in a migration function has no effect. This is because [migrations are executed as part of a transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/migration/Migration#migrate(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)) and [the pragma is a no-op inside a transaction](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#:~:text=PRAGMA%20foreign_keys%20%3D%20boolean%3B,no%20pending%20BEGIN%20or%20SAVEPOINT.).

I don't see any way to get control and enable `foreign_keys` before the migration is executed.  I think your only option is to delete the pets explicitly as part of the migration:

```
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    database.execSQL("""
        DELETE FROM pets WHERE owner_id IN (SELECT id FROM users)
    """)

    database.execSQL("""
        DELETE FROM users
    """)
}
```