# Why Android Room Instrument Testing Framework unable to detect FOREIGN KEY constraint failed?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-room

I try to perform instrument test on Emulator, to unit test my Room DB migration code - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db

However, I notice that the test unable to detect FOREIGN KEY constraint failed.

For instance, if the run the following commands in SQLite directly, by using https://sqlitebrowser.org/

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `plain_note`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attachment`;
CREATE TABLE `plain_note` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE `attachment` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`plain_note_id`) REFERENCES `plain_note`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE );
INSERT INTO "main"."attachment" ("id", "plain_note_id") VALUES ('1', '2');
```

Last line will throw exception

```
Result: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

As `attachment` is trying to refer to `plain_note`'s id 2, but `plain_note`'s id 2 is non existence.

However, when I write the following instrument test. The unit test passed!

---

### Not able to detect FOREIGN KEY constraint

```
public class Migration_26_27Test {
    private static final String TEST_DB = "migration-test";

    @Rule
    public MigrationTestHelper helper;

    public Migration_26_27Test() {
        helper = new MigrationTestHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
                MyRoomDatabase.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 26);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `plain_note`;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attachment`;");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `plain_note` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `attachment` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `plain_note_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`plain_note_id`) REFERENCES `plain_note`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE );");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO \"main\".\"attachment\" (\"id\", \"plain_note_id\") VALUES ('1', '2');");
    }
}
```

The instrument test passed WITHOUT issue!

I did further testing, to check whether it is able to detect NON NULL constraint.

---

### Able to detect NON NULL constraint

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class Migration_26_27Test {
    private static final String TEST_DB = "migration-test";

    @Rule
    public MigrationTestHelper helper;

    public Migration_26_27Test() {
        helper = new MigrationTestHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
                WeNoteRoomDatabase.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 26);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `plain_note`;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attachment`;");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `plain_note` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `attachment` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `plain_note_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`plain_note_id`) REFERENCES `plain_note`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE );");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO \"main\".\"attachment\" (\"id\", \"plain_note_id\") VALUES ('1', NULL);");
    }
}
```

It will fail with

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: attachment.plain_note_id (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
```

---

May I know why it is not able to detect FOREIGN KEY constraint failure? How can I make the test fails when FOREIGN KEY constraint violated?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Room's `onDelete = CASCADE` not working during a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064932/rooms-ondelete-cascade-not-working-during-a-migration)

It seems that during Android Room migration, the foreign key constraint is being turned off.